# If $T\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb R)$ invertible, why is $T^tT$ positive definite?

Tags: matrices

Let $T\in \mathcal M_{n\times n}(\mathbb R)$ invertible, why is $T^tT$ positive definite?

My only idea is $$x^tT^tTx=(Tx)^t(Tx)=\|Tx\|^2,$$
and since $T$ invertible $\|Tx\|=0$ only if $x=0$, but I don't think it's a good argument.

Comment: It is correct. You have shown that $x\ne 0\implies x^TT^TTx>0.$ Why do you have doubts?

Comment: What's wrong about it? It's the natural way of doing it!

Comment: Could you explain why you "don't think it's a good argument"?